# How can I find out what image was used to build an AzureVM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When building a new VM on Azure, you have many different OS options available to choose from.  How can I find out which option was used for an existing VM?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or need more help please give me the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure CLI command to get the image information that used in the existing VM:

```
az vm show -g resourceGroupName -n vmName -d --query storageProfile.imageReference
```

Or get the available images for VM/VMSS in Azure with the command [`az vm image list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-image-list).

Hope this will help you. If you need more help please give me the message.